# Помогите найти ошибку в цикле

Tags: matlab

Программа считает оптический элемент,размеры его x и y,шаг d. 
В первом цикле x рассчитывается правильно,получается строка значений от -x0./2 до x0./2 с шагом d нужной размерности.А во втором,в y,я получаю вот такое число на выходе,последним значением 121761,928101454.
Число шагов и размерность там верная,шаги считаются,только откуда программа берёт за начальное значение это число если оно у меня задано y1=-y0./2
Подскажите пожалуйста,в чем может быть ошибка?

```
L=10.6*10^-3;
A=45;
x0=str2num(get(edit1, 'String'));
F=str2num(get(edit2, 'String')); 
d=str2num(get(edit3, 'String')); 
y0=x0./cos(A);
d=d.*10.^-3;
sizex=fix(x0/d);
sizey=fix(y0/d);
x1=-x0./2;
y1=-y0./2;

for i=1:1:sizex
    x(i)=x1+d;
   for j=1:1:sizey
       y(j)=y1+d;
        if cos(pi.*((x(i).*x(i)+y(j).*y(j))./(L.*F)))>0 
           h(i,j)=1;
        else
           h(i,j)=0;
        end;
        y1=y(j);
    end;
x1=x(i);
end;
```

Comment: вы же учли, что cos принимает радианы?

Comment: У меня значения по y получаются бредовые,косинусы соответственно тоже странные выходят

Comment: у вас изначально при инициализации y0=x0./cos(A); вы тут понимаете, что cos(45) это косинус не от 45 градусов? если вы хотите от косинус от градусов, то используйте cosd(45)

Comment: Спасибо вам за замечание,там тоже ошибочка была,но и ранее y0 имел адекватные значения,около 70,при x0=40. y1 до начала цикла имеет нормальные значения,огромными они становятся когда я добавляю в конце цикла y1=y(j); чтобы следующий цикл начался с последнего значения+шаг